# Rails, proxy request to another url without starting an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, router

I have a Rails app running on e.g. example.com. 
Any request is processed by Rails router.

There is public API on e.g. example.com/rest/2.0/session.
API is done on PHP and is unrelated to main app.

Is it possible to proxy requests to API bypassing Rails application?

Sorry in advance, no clues found in internet.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring directories in apache.

You can have your rails application in /var/www/ruby/myapp and PHP api code in /var/www/php/.

Comment: Yeah, proxy_pass, but unfortunately Rails comes with WEBrick as default server. I found nothing about setting up proxy pass on WEBrick.

Comment: I use webrick as testing server, for production environments check apache or nginx + passenger.